# sql alchemy session calling a different table

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

```
class KtOwnerAddressMaster(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'kt_owner_address_master'
    ADDRESS_ID = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    STREET1 = db.Column(String(1024), nullable=False)
    STREET2 = db.Column(String(1024))
    ZIP = db.Column(String(15))
    CITY_NAME = db.Column(String(200))
    STATE = db.Column(String(200))
    COUNTRY = db.Column(String(200))
    ADDR_EXT_ID = db.Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    CREATED_ON = db.Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    UPDATED_ON = db.Column(DateTime)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     super(KtOwnerAddressMaster, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     return
class KtOwnerAddressMap(KtOwnerAddressMaster):
    __tablename__ = 'kt_owner_address_map'
    ADDRESS_ID =db.Column(ForeignKey(u'kt_owner_address_master.ADDRESS_ID'), primary_key=True)
    CURRENT_ADDR = db.Column(SmallInteger, nullable=False, server_default=text("'0'"))
    FRIENDLY_NAME = db.Column(String(100))
    OWNER_ID = db.Column(ForeignKey(u'kt_owner_master.OWNER_ID'), nullable=False, index=True)

    kt_owner_master = relationship(u'KtOwnerMaster')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(KtOwnerAddressMap, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    return
```

And in my views I am doing the following :

```
    ad_object=KtOwnerAddressMaster(STREET1=street1,
                                   STREET2=street2,
                                   ZIP=zipcode,
                                   ADDR_EXT_ID=addr_ext_id,                          
          CREATED_ON=datetime.now().strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"),                            
          UPDATED_ON=datetime.now().strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                    CITY_NAME =city_name,
                                    STATE=state,
                                    COUNTRY=country)

        db.session.add(ad_object)
        db.session.commit()

    addr_obj=db.session.query(KtOwnerAddressMaster).filter_by(ADDR_EXT_ID=addr_ext_id).with_entities(KtOwnerAddressMaster.ADDRESS_ID).first()
    address_id=int(addr_obj[0])
```

Now I am trying to add a address map to the owner address map table.

```
    add_object=KtOwnerAddressMap(ADDRESS_ID=address_id,
                         CURRENT_ADDR="current_addr",
                         FRIENDLY_NAME="friendly_name",
                         OWNER_ID=owner_id)

    db.session.add(add_object)
    #The error appears on the below commit 
    db.session.commit()
```

I am able to see the address being populated in the database. But I am not able to insert owner to address mapping in the table.
It Gives me the following error :
(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1048, "Column 'STREET1' cannot be null") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO kt_owner_address_master (`ADDRESS_ID`, `STREET1`, `STREET2`, `ZIP`, `CITY_NAME`, `STATE`, `COUNTRY`, `ADDR_EXT_ID`, `CREATED_ON`, `UPDATED_ON`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: (51, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)]

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the flaw. There was a typo in my code.

```
    class KtOwnerAddressMap(KtOwnerAddressMaster):
```

It should have been.

```
    class KtOwnerAddressMap(db.Model):
```

Dont know how I ended up doing this.
All good now!!